# PlusClient calls onConnected without network connection

Tags: android, google-plus

I have a native Google+ button in my app, and when it gets clicked, I call the `PlusClient.connect()` method for my activity and all usually runs just fine.

in my testing phase, I saw that even after disconnecting from any network service, the client still arrived in the `onConnected` method even though I'm sure there is no way of doing this.

can anyone offer an explanation as to how the client thinks I'm connected if I cannot be?

here is my code for this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    didUserClickDone = false;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.profile_google_plus_signin:
        if(mPlusClient != null && !mPlusClient.isConnected()){
            if (mConnectionResult == null) {
            } else {
                try {
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                            REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    // Try connecting again.

                }
            }
            mConnectionResult = null;
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this,
                    REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start resolution with error", e);
            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, R.string.activity_profile_google_plus_failure_toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    mConnectionResult = result;   
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if(mPlusClient.isConnected()){
        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, R.string.activity_profile_google_plus_success_toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getUserInfoFromGooglePlus();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, R.string.activity_profile_google_plus_failure_toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
}

private void getUserInfoFromGooglePlus() {
    if(mPlusClient.isConnected()){
        // DO AWESOME STUFF

        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
        mPlusClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

after running this I always get the Toast for successful login, even if I have no network. why?